# UITableView reload section weird behaviour on iOS 8.x

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a UITableView contains list of sections, each section represents a shipment and has its own tick (like a checkbox) to select the section.

Now, whenever a user taps on any of these sections i need to update/reload the total amount section (a section that calculates the required due amount).

So i have PaymentSelectionTableViewSection (custom section class) that takes shipment model, boolean value to determine if the section is selected or not and a tap handler, this tap handler is as below:

```
self.shipments.map({ PaymentSelectionTableViewSection(shipment: $0.shipment, selected: $0.selected) 
{ tableView, indexPath in
        self.shipments[indexPath.section - 1].selected = !self.shipments[indexPath.section - 1].selected

        if let totalsSection = self.totalsSection {
            self.sections[self.shipments.count + 1] = totalsSection
            tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: self.shipments.count + 1), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
        }
    }})
```

I get weird behaviour whenever i reload that section, the behaviour is sliding the whole tableview from bottom to top and then reloading this section.
It only occurs in iOS 8.x.x and works fine in iOS 9.x.x

I made a video for this behaviour as follows:
https://vid.me/CyED

Comment: Change `UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic` to whatever direction you want.

Comment: @NickAllen whatever UITableViewRowAnimation you choose it does the same behaviour, it refreshes the whole tableView though it works fine in iOS9.

Comment: I have the same problem. If I reload the whole tableView it works fine.